# Send Firebase Token from Android to Google Cloud Endpoints

Tags: android, google-app-engine, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-endpoints

I am integrating Firebase Authentication into my Android App. After successful login, the Android App will call some Google Cloud Endpoints running on Google App Engine.

So I need to pass the Firebase Token I received from the Authentication to the Google Cloud Endpoints. I am using the following code to call the endpoints ([source](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/helloendpoints-android-studio))

```
MyApi.Builder builder = new MyApi.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(),
                new AndroidJsonFactory(), null)
myApiService = builder.build();

myApiService.sayHi(name).execute();
```

So how can I forward the token to my backend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `HttpRequestInitializer` to inject the token:

```
HttpRequestInitializer requestInitializer = new HttpRequestInitializer() {
  @Override
  public void initialize(HttpRequest request) throws IOException {
    HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    httpHeaders.setAuthorization("Bearer " + getFirebaseToken());
    request.setHeaders(httpHeaders);
  }
};

MyApi.Builder builder = new MyApi.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(),
            new AndroidJsonFactory(), requestInitializer)
myApiService = builder.build();
```