# How can I get Google Cloud Endpoints to work for authenticated calls with Firebase Auth (non-Google Account)?

Tags: android, google-app-engine, oauth-2.0, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-endpoints

I've got an API set up with Google Cloud Endpoints Frameworks. One of the endpoints requires auth which can apparently be done with Firebase Auth on Android. But the example given [here](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/java/calling-from-android#configuring_your_android_client_to_provide_credentials) is for Google accounts through Firebase. I'm just using email and password. So I'm using the HttpRequestInitializer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41329587/send-firebase-token-from-android-to-google-cloud-endpoints) instead of the GoogleAccountCredential one. But when I attempt to make calls to the authenticated endpoint I get a 503 response with the server producing the following stack trace:

```
Uncaught exception from servlet
java.lang.IllegalStateException: method_info is not set in the request
    at com.google.api.server.spi.auth.EspAuthenticator.authenticate(EspAuthenticator.java:67)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.request.Auth.authenticate(Auth.java:85)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.request.ServletRequestParamReader.getUser(ServletRequestParamReader.java:157)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.request.ServletRequestParamReader.deserializeParams(ServletRequestParamReader.java:114)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.request.ServletRequestParamReader.read(ServletRequestParamReader.java:261)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemService.invokeServiceMethod(SystemService.java:354)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet.execute(SystemServiceServlet.java:113)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet.doPost(SystemServiceServlet.java:71)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    ...
```

Any ideas?

Firebase Auth itself is set up correctly because I can make calls to the Firebase real-time database to areas that need auth. And the endpoint is set up correctly because I can make unauthenticated calls to my other endpoints (which don't currently need authentication). It's just the combination of the two that is broken.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in your [Google Groups post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-cloud-endpoints/40RhzFFAmfg), you need to remove the SystemServiceServlet from your config, and also remove the com.google.appengine:appengine-endpoints dependency from your list.